# Jboss eap-7.2: Adding external directory to a class-path

Tags: server, jboss, jboss-eap-7

As per project need we need to migrate from `jboss-eap-5.1.2` to `jboss-eap-7.2` and for testing I was trying to deploy the war file in `jboss-7.2`.
But it started giving me exception

> rom relative location [mailsender.xml]
>   Offending resource: class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreExcept
>   ion: IOException parsing XML document from URL [vfs:/C:/dev/migration/jboss-eap-7.2-eap/bin/content/basel.war/WEB-INF/classes/mailsender.xml]; ne
>   sted exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\migration\jboss-eap-7.2-eap\standalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tempc01c1475a2367060\content-53d16429
>   03fec06a\WEB-INF\classes\mailsender.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

i.e. file `mailsender.xml` is not added in the classpath.
**Query :** Is there any way in jboss-eap-7.2 to add a external folder(where I can put all of my XML's which needs to be present at the classpath) to classpath?

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in JBOSS EAP 7.1, where  APP-INF/classes resource folder in ear or war:
add META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml with similar config:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="APP-INF/classes" />
        </resources>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```